# setxkbmap - toggle doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, layout, toggle

I've tried all of the "grp:*_toggle" options one by one and none of them works.

% setxkbmap -option; setxkbmap -query                                                                                                                15:29:07 2014-06-05 !1817
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ru

Ubuntu 14.04, all the latest updates are installed.
I've seen similar problems with iBus in Ubuntu forums but I've removed it long ago (and installing it back didn't solve the issue).
Also I've tried to change my UID (someone's suggested it) but to no avail.

Is there anything I can do if not to solve but at least to pinpoint this problem?

Comment: Also I have kbdd running and
`dbus-send --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.next_layout`
command changes the layout for kbdd (querying it later returns proper layout) but the actual layout is still "us".